# Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.aiven.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to ingest data from kafka to postgres for which i have to connect kafka and postgres.I have used io.aiven.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector.My standalone.properties file is given below:

```
rest.port=8084
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java
```

Below is the jdbc- sink connector file:

```
name=example-jdbc-sink

# These are defaults, but they're here for clarity:
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

connector.class=io.aiven.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/advicedb?user=**&password=***

topics=messages

# This is default, but it's here for clarity:
insert.mode=insert
```

Now the problem is when I am running the connector with the command  `bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/jdbc-sink.properties`
it is giving the following error:

```
ERROR Failed to create job for config/jdbc-sink.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:107)
[2022-02-10 15:15:05,764] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:117)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.aiven.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector,
```

I have checked the path, the files are on the right directory but its still not working. i have java version 11 and ubuntu 20.04

Comment: What files did you download? And what did you change between your last question and this where you already had a jdbc sink? Also, the Confluent JDBC Sink is the most commonly used. Use confluent hub to install it https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc

Comment: previous one was ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink connector and this one is io.aiven.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector. the issue was with the datatype.

Comment: Still, the IBM connector should have been installed similar to the Aiven one, so the error here indicates you've messed up the plugin path somehow, or you've not downloaded the correct files